# C# late binding to com/activeX server, trouble with one method

Tags: c#, com, interop, reference

I am fairly new to Interop/Com/ActiveX etc, so bear with me.

I am late binding into a com/activex (not sure which one) server (basically an exe not a dll). I am successfully using all the methods in that server except for one, here is the description:

> VT_INT GetLastCCTError (variant
>   *error_string);
>
> **Description**: This function is used to retrieve the last error generated
>   by the CCT. The function may be called
>   at any point as long as the CCT Server
>   is initialized. If no error has
>   occurred when the function is called,
>   the returned code is ‘0’ (zero), and
>   the error string will be empty. Only
>   the last error that occurred during
>   the current run of the CCT Server will
>   be available.
>
> **Input**: None
>
> **Output**: The function returns a single output parameter,
>   ‘error_string’ of type VARTYPE VT_BSTR
>   | VT_BYREF. The parameter contains an
>   error string for the error code
>   associated with the last CCT function
>   failure. Return Value: This function
>   returns an integer value of type
>   VT_INT. This is the error code
>   associated with the last CCT function
>   failure

I first tried using this code:

```
this.LastErrorCode = (int)CCTType.InvokeMember("GetLastCCTError", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, CCTObject, new object[] {this.LastErrorString});
```

I got the following exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)

Then after some thinking I changed the code to:

```
object[] Args = { "SomeString" };

this.LastErrorCode = (int)CCTType.InvokeMember("GetLastCCTError", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, CCTObject, Args);
```

Still the same error. After some googling, I found this article: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27219&seqNum=8

If you look at section 3.3 it seems to be the solution to my problem, and thus I changed my code to:

```
object[] Args = { "SomeString" };

ParameterModifier ParMod = new ParameterModifier(1);
ParMod[0] = true;
ParameterModifier[] ArrParMod = { ParMod };

this.LastErrorCode = (int)CCTType.InvokeMember("GetLastCCTError", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, CCTObject, Args, ArrParMod, null, null);

this.LastErrorString = (string) Args[0];
```

This still results in the same exception. I am now thinking that the problem might not be the reference passing but something else. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just for interest sake. I tried calling the method in VB and it works with the following code:
        Dim CCTObject As Object
        CCTObject = CreateObject("CCTServer.Document")
        Dim Result = CCTObject.InitializeDevice("Camera")

        Dim ms As String
        Result = CCTObject.GetLastCCTError(ms)

Answer (score 1):

Is this because strings in C# are immutable.

"SomeString" will be resolved by the compiler as an unchangeable string on the managed memory (stack or heap is largely irrelevant in your case).

So, in a way you are not passing in a string reference but a literal - something that could never be an 'out' parameter as in your example ... so the marshalling won't do what it thinks (knows) would be a bad idea.

Andrew D, I suspect, is right.

Might suggest you try something like:

```
StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();

this.LastErrorCode = (int)CCTType.InvokeMember("GetLastCCTError", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, CCTObject, errorMessage );

this.LastErrorString = errorMessage.ToString();
```

Regards,

Aidanapword